# How to to break down with Langchain whether it's mathematical question or "general"

Tags: pandas, langchain, large-language-model

I'm trying to generate an internal tool with Langchain that would take as an input some sales data as well as work like a general bot. So I could ask it to write me a poem and then ask about YoY growth fro last year?

Currently my code looks like this. Would the right way forward be to build an agent that determines whether the user input goes to pandasAI or for example LLMChain?

```
import pandas as pd
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import PandasAI

openai_api_key = "API KEY"

model = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key=openai_api_key)


def chat_with_csv(df,prompt):
    llm = OpenAI(api_token=openai_api_key)
    pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)
    result = pandas_ai.run(df, prompt=prompt)
    return result

data = pd.read_csv('/content/ComputerSales.csv')


while True:
  input_text = input("Enter your query: ")
  result = chat_with_csv(data, input_text)
  print(result)
```

**Targeted way of working:**
What is the capital of sweden?
==> Stockholm

What is the YoY growth from 2018 onwards
==>
2018: x%
2019: x%
2020: x%
2021: x%
2022: x%

Comment: You could incorporate a classification function or model to identify whether the query pertains to general knowledge or your sales data. This could be as simple as looking for certain keywords or as complex as training a machine learning model to classify the intent of the query.

Comment: https://github.com/langchain-ai/streamlit-agent/blob/main/streamlit_agent/mrkl_demo.py is all you need